# Why can't I set this boolean component variable with my toggle() function?

Tags: angular, this

This seems straightforward.  I have an Angular 6 component which shows a row of a table and conditionally shows some detail (of orders for the product):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[app-product-row]',
  templateUrl: './product-row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-row.component.css']
})
export class ProductRowComponent implements OnInit {

  show: boolean = false;
  @Input() product: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleDetail() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

  get orders() {
    return this.show ? this.product.orders : null;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `toggleDetail()` function has no effect on the `show` variable outside of the function.  If I add some `console.log()` lines for debugging, like so...

```
  toggleDetail() {
    console.log(this.show);
    this.show = !this.show;
    console.log(this.show);
  }
```

...it logs 'false' and then 'true' every time I trigger the `toggleDetail()` function with a mouse click event.  But on a subsequent click it does the same thing; the `show` variable is never actually set to `true`.  What am I getting wrong?  Something about the `this` keyword maybe?

## Edit: some more context

This component is generated with an *ngFor in the parent template in the following way:

```
  <tbody app-product-row *ngFor="let p of group.products; let i = index;" [rownum]="i+1"></tbody>
```

And the template itself looks like this:

```
<tr (click)="toggleDetail()">
  <td>{{product.sku}}</td>
  <td>{{product.oldest|date:'M/d/yyyy'}}</td>
  <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{product.amount|currency:'USD':'symbol':'1.0-0'}}</td>
</tr>

<tr *ngFor="let o of orders">
  <td>{{o.customer}}</td>
  <td>{{o.planned_date}}</td>
  <td>{{o.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{o.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is the first time I've called a component in this way (as an attribute on another element (`<tbody>`) instead of as a tag of its own (eg. `<app-product-row>`).  Maybe that changes things somehow?

## Edit 2: maybe *ngFor is the problem?

I have tried a simple test in the component and the parent components, creating a boolean variable `booly` in the parent component and a simple onClick event to toggle it:

```
<p (click)="booly=!booly;">component-name: {{booly}}</p>
```

This works correctly in parent components *not* instantiated as part of a loop.  In each child component instantiated with an `*ngFor` directive, though, the boolean variable fails to toggle.  This includes some that are invoked with element selectors (`<component-name>`) and some with attribute selectors (e.g. `<tr component-name>`) so I think it's the loop that's the issue.  I'm still stumped as to how to solve it, though.

Comment: I cannot repro this. Works like a charm.

Comment: Your toggle function is working absolutely fine. Look for your firing event. I have tried ` <button type="button" (click)= "toggleDetail()" >Button</button>` it works.

Comment: The firing event works. Same results when I switch to a button.  I've just edited the question with more context; maybe it's something to do with how I invoke the component.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something going on here that we can't see from the provided code, but to eliminate most possible causes of this, you can just do:

```
<tr (click)="show = !show">
```

in your template.

Comment: That actually doesn't fix it.  I wonder if the problem might be due to the way I invoke the component, so I edited the question with more context.

Comment: I agree that seems like a likely explanation. Can you try adding `console.log("app-product-row init");` to your ngOnInit() method and post the result here?

Comment: It prints that line to the console (once per product row) but the behavior of the toggle function is the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of suggestions then. If you'd like to create a minimal example in stackblitz or plunker I'll take a look at it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of your `get orders()` function and instead have orders be an array like this

```
orders = [];
toggleDetail() {
  this.show = !this.show;
  this.orders = this.show ? this.product.orders : [];
}
```

**EDIT:** Try to display the current `this.orders` in the html. That may help you figure out what is happening.

**typescript**

```
orders = [];
temp = ''; //new
toggleDetail() {
  this.show = !this.show;
  this.orders = this.show ? this.product.orders : [];
  console.log(this.orders); //new
  temp = JSON.stringify(this.orders); //new
}
```

**html**

```
{{temp}} <!--new-->
<tr *ngFor="let o of orders">
   ...
```

Comment: Good idea, but the change to `this.orders` also doesn't survive the function's execution.

Comment: hmm... it should. maybe to help you with debugging, look at my edit to see what the actual value of `this.orders` is

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, the bug is a result or side-effect of the `*ngFor` loops.  Angular was simply destroying and re-creating my nested tables and rows every time a click event happened, so the local component variable simply wasn't persisting.

I solved this by doing all my looping logic in the parent component (not itself instantiated in a loop), and instead of a true/false "show" variable on each row, I added a parameter to the data service itself (i.e. "show details for this one") so the detail rows are either included or not included in the data.  (Hence no `*ngIf` is needed.)

I suspect there may be another way to solve this by configuring Angular's change detection/ change handling settings to prevent the components from being destroyed and recreated.  If anybody knows it, post an answer!